# How to access the PARSE rest api?

Tags: angularjs, parse-platform

I am using parse.com for the data side of my app. I am new to parse and angular, I was wondering how do i access my rest api, when i put the url in it asks for a username and password but which one?

Also is there a specific way to use the rest api?

Comment: maybe this wrapper could help: https://github.com/brandid/parse-angular-demo

Comment: Thanks will look into that....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are looking for the REST API docs, which can be found here:
http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/

Go through the 'Getting Started' section, it lays out in excellent detail how to address the API and gives good examples.

Regarding the login/pass, Parse requires you to create a User object in order to use the REST API; it's asking you for a User so the DB knows what level of access you have to various objects. ([Parse uses ACLs, access control lists](http://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/#user-security), for user security. ACLs are your friend, learn them.)

Good luck in your new endeavor!

Comment: I do understand how it works but for example, if i try out a class in the api console and then try that same one in a url: https://api.parse.com/class/example.... the url requests a password and login but which one is not stated anywhere, unless i have missed something

Comment: I edited my answer for clarification on the login/pass issue. Good question.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @krokodilko! I updated the links to the new Parse Platform website.